# Object slicing in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the base object from derived object in php

Something like this

```
class base {}
class derived extends base{
public function getBase()
{
         return (base)$this;
}
```

The above code, throws out a error

Comment: Can you provide more details on the why please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parent::` to resolve to a parent method, property or constant.

Comment: but can we return the base object itself

Comment: @Akash An instantiated object from the parent class? What if the parent class is `abstract`?

Comment: the one instantiated from the derived class

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the *name* of the base class, here's a way to do that:

```
class base {
  public function getClassName() {
    return "base";
  }
}
class derived extends base{
  public function getBaseClassName() {
    return parent::getClassName();
  }
  public function getClassName() {
    return "derived";
  }
}

$d = new derived();
echo $d->getBaseClassName();
```

---

**Edit**: When you use inheritance to extend a class (eg: `derived extends base`), you are saying that `derived` *is a kind of* `base`, and all instances of `derived` *are also* instances of `base`.  In most OO languages, the two instances, `base` and `derived` are not separate entities, and they can not be treated separately. (C++ is an exception to the rule in this regard).

If you need to treat the instances separately, then inheritance is the wrong tool for the job.  Use extension by *containment*, rather than inheritance.  This will look something like the following:

```
class base {

  public someBaseFunction() { 
    // ...
  }
}

class derived {

  /**
   * each instance of `derived` *contains* an in instance of `base`
   * that instance will be stored in this protected property
   */
  protected $base;

  /**
   * constructor
   */
  function __construct() {

    // remember to call base's constructor
    // passing along whatever parameters (if any) are needed
    $this->base = new base();

    // ... now do your constructor logic, if any ...

  }

  /**
   * Here's the method that fetches the contained
   * instance of `base`
   */
  public function getBase() {
    return $this->base;
  }

  /**
   * If needed, `derived` can implement public elements
   * from `base`'s interface. The logic can either delegate
   * directly to the contained instance of base, or it can
   * do something specific to `derived`, thus "overriding" 
   * `base`'s implementation.
   */
  public function someBaseFunction() {
    return $this->base->someBaseFunction();
  }

  /**
   * of course, `derived` can implement its own public
   * interface as well...
   */
  public function someOtherFunction() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I wish to get the base object itself from the derived one

Comment: but the derived instance *is* the base instance.  That's what class inheritance is about.